# MATLAB: How to get variables from GUI m-file into Simulink Model

Tags: user-interface, simulink, matlab

Hey guys, I dont know if I'm wording my problem right but I have created a GUI, an m-file and a simulink. Initially I had the variables going from the m-file into the Simulink, but now I want the user to be able to change the variables so I have created a GUI. I keep getting an error though, I dont think the variables are going from the GUI m-file to the simulink model anymore. I remember you had to set something to do it, like simset or setcurrentsim or something but I cannot remember, so I was wondering can anyone help me with this one?

Comment: Please add the error message to your post.

Comment: I'm not totally sure of what your problem is, but I *think* this is probably a duplicate of this question: [How do I get data from a Simulink block into a MATLAB GUI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245173/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-simulink-block-into-a-matlab-gui). Even if it isn't a duplicate, I think there is some helpful information there which may guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the set_param command.

It should look something like this:

```
set_param('model name/block name','block type',string);
```

In my code I have a model called Pitch_Control with a Gain block called Pitch Rate Sensor.
k2 is an integer.

```
set_param('Pitch_Control/Pitch Rate Sensor','Gain',num2str(k2));
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`set_param` works, however it is a pretty specific way and should only be used to change block settings and not to pass parameters.

What you are looking for is [assignin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html?nocookie=true).
You go with: `assignin('base','Parametername',value);`
Since Simulink imports variables from the base-workspace it does the same as your old script would have done.