# Plotting in Matlab using Real Time data from Simulink

Tags: matlab, plot, real-time, simulink, sampling

I'm trying to solve a problem of simulating in real time in Simulink (This is solved) but plotting (real time) in Matlab ?

**Details:**

*I want to be able to run a Simulink simulation (which is running in real time) and be able to turn on / off manual switches while the simulation is happening. This works well when I'm using the built in Scopes in Simulink but now I want to export that data to Matlab in real time as well (To make a custom looking graph).*

*So is there a way, to export this data (it can be sampled if that is necessary)  to Matlab and make a plot that is constantly updating. Meanwhile I can still manipulate the switches in Simulink and influence the simulation manually ?
Simulink is effectively running continuously until I stop it.*

**Thanks for the help!**

Comment: How to do this (and how easy/hard it may be to do) depends a little on what real-time OS you are using and what the communications protocol is being used between the (non-real time) Simulink window and the underlying real-time code.  But this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24294-simulink-signal-viewing-using-event-listeners-and-a-matlab-ui) may give you some ideas.

Comment: Nice catch. I will see if I can't change this example to my advantage! :) Thanks

Comment: Phil is correct, the only way to do this is with an event listener. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245173/how-do-i-get-data-from-a-simulink-block-into-a-matlab-gui

Answer (score -1):

There should be some kind of notification going when simulink updates the data to be visualized. Maybe this is the [`linkdata`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/linkdata.html) feature.

Another, worse, solution is the [`drawnow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278368/matlab-real-time-plot) command to redraw the graphs continously (the latter could be unnescessary costly for you program).

Comment: The `linkdata` does not work because the data in the workspace is only updated/written once the simulation is complete and the OP wants to plot the data while the simulation is running. `drawnow` doesn't help either for the same reason.